# Groovy SQL + Gorm under same session/transaction

Tags: sql, grails, groovy, grails-orm, transactional

Please go through the simple scenario below, I couldn't find a better way to ask the question in textual form:

Two domain objects and a transactional service:

```
A {
 int id
 String prop1
 B b
 static constraints = {b nullable:true}
}

B {
 int id
 String prop1
 // not worring about belongsTo here
}



SomeService {

 def transactional = true
 def sessionFactory

 def aTransactionalMethod() {
  Sql sql = new Sql(sessionFactory.currentSession.connection())

  sql# create A some how with sql query leaving property b as null.

 A a = A.findById(...)
 //a.b must be null here, never mind

 sql# create B object somehow with sql query.

 // should a.b be available now? I'm getting null here.. session.currentSession.refresh(a) resolves the issue but why is that?
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate can't parse SQL, so it doesn't "know" what you write to database. Hibernate will not reload all session objects - that would definitely be huge overhead.

Maybe if you rewrite your query to HQL the objects will become available to session in immediately.

Comment: Yup this seems to be the only way to achieve this. But not all SQL can be written easily in HQL. I'll better convert all reads to SQL as well. Gorm is just of no use to me here as I need to write through Stored Procedures only.

Comment: if you wish to take advantage of GORM, you could try to tune Hibernate mapping for stored procedures or arbitrary SQL: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query